# GUI asynchronous update failed

Tags: c#, user-interface, asynchronous, callback

I am trying to update the `TextBox` and `ListView` simultaneously.  However, I cannot. The `Listview` is updating, but the `TextBox` is only updating sometimes.

```
private void updateGUI(ISynchronizeInvoke asyncInvoke, Action action)
{
    try
    {
        if (!asyncInvoke.InvokeRequired)
            action();
        else
            asyncInvoke.BeginInvoke(action, new object[] { });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("update gui error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}

// CallBack for update GUI
private void onProgressChange(object source, DownloadEventArgs e)
{
    // Update ListView and TextBox
    this.updateGUI
    (
        this.lstDownloads,
        () =>
        {
            this.downloadTotalSize += e.currentDlBytes;

            this.lstDownloads.Items[e.downloadIndex].SubItems[1].Text = e.downloadBytes;
            this.lstDownloads.Items[e.downloadIndex].SubItems[2].Text = e.downloadProgress + "%";

            this.lblDownloadSize.Text = e.downloadBytes + " / " + this.downloadTotalSize
        }
    );
}
```

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong? Sorry for typos. Regards.

Comment: I don't understand why do you need two calls to `updateGUI`. Can't it be single? That should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks @Sriram. You're right, I believed I had to use the method to invoke 2 times already that are two gui components (listview and textbox). I updated the code. Now it's more faster, but still slow. It is possible to totally asynchronous update of the 2 components?

Comment: How often `onProgressChange` will be called?

Comment: @Sriram, onProgressChange called quite a few times depending on how many files I download simultaneously. When I have only one file downloading, the gui is updated perfectly, but when I have about 5 files downloading, start the GUI update problem.

Comment: How about updating the UI in timer and just adding the  onProgressChange info in a collection which will be processed by timer?

Comment: @Sriram, honestly I had already thought about that option but this seems to me more elegant way. So do you advise replacing the callback for a timer for update the gui?

Comment: Yes if the callbacks are large in number and often, you need to think about using a timer. Consider there are 20 or more updates/sec. who is going to see that? it is not much helpful no human can watch that. If I were doing this I'd go for timer, later don't forget to stop the timer when there are no items for a while

Comment: @Sriram, thank you very much. As I said before, i already had thought about, but I wanted to hear it from some veteran :) If you want post a answer, so I accept your answer.